# Convert file to byte array then to string then to byte array then to the original file

Tags: java, string, file, bitarray

I'm trying (In Java) to get a file document then convert it to bitArray afterwards to a String of similar representation, then back to the original bit array and finally to the original final document.

Here is my code, But the file generated is not viewable in this case the image.

```
try {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/dkimigho/Downloads/kenyapowerlogo.jpg");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //create FileInputStream which obtains input bytes from a file in a file system
        //FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                //Writes to this byte array output stream
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ARRAYBITStoPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("byte1");
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        }
        //We have the bytes now convert to String
        String stringbytearray=new String(bytes);

        System.out.println("stringbytearray: "+stringbytearray);

        //We have the bytes now convert to String

        byte[] content = stringbytearray.getBytes();
        System.out.println("byte2");
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(content[i]);
        }

        int size = bytes.length;
        InputStream isfilecontent = null;
        byte[] b = new byte[size];
        isfilecontent = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);

        //writing the downloaded data into a PDF file
         FileOutputStream fileOutputpdf = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/dkimigho/Downloads/mykenyapowerlogo.jpg");

         /* use binary I/O to prevent line based operation messing with the encoding.*/
         byte[] buf2 = new byte[2048];
         int b_read = 0;
         while ( (b_read = isfilecontent.read(buf2)) > 0) {
             fileOutputpdf.write(buf2, 0, b_read);
         }
         fileOutputpdf.flush();
         //closed the output stream
         fileOutputpdf.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle IOException
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Any help on pointing what I'm doing wrong? A correction of my code to a working one may be important.

Comment: Any help pointing what doesn't work ? You should have on method per functionnality. This would be easier to test what works, and what doesn't. And you should start with a simple text file ... a jpg is more complex to check the value step by step.

Comment: Java doc : `String(byte[] bytes) Constructs a new String by **decoding** the specified array of bytes **using the platform's default charset**.` I think this modify your content

Comment: Converting bytes to a String corrupts/alters them.  You can store bytes in a string in C, but you cannot do that in Java.  In Java, you store bytes in a byte array or [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).  Do not use Strings at all here.

Comment: What is your intention, your use case? Trying to interpret the bytes of a JPEG file as a string doesn't make any sense. Or do you mean you want a string representation of the bytes like Base64 which is used to transfer binary data over a text protocol?

Comment: Yes I want a string representation of the bytes like Base64 which is used to transfer binary data over a using htttp but in an xml node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer one has to use JAVA 8 java.util.Base64 to encode and decode the bytes without loosing information on the document. I hope it will be of help to someone.

```
/*
     * 1. How to convert an image file to  byte array?
     */
    try {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/qwerty/Downloads/factura.pdf");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //create FileInputStream which obtains input bytes from a file in a file system
        //FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                //Writes to this byte array output stream
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
               // System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ARRAYBITStoPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close(); // should be inside a finally block
        //We have the bytes now convert to String

        // ENCODING
        String encodedDoc= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

        System.out.println(encodedDoc);

        // DECODING
        int size = bytes.length;
        InputStream isfilecontent = null;
        //byte[] b = new byte[size];
        isfilecontent = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedDoc));

        //writing the downloaded data into a PDF file
         FileOutputStream fileOutputpdf = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/qwerty/Downloads/myfactura.pdf");

         /* use binary I/O to prevent line based operation messing with the encoding.*/
         byte[] buf2 = new byte[2048];
         int b_read = 0;
         while ( (b_read = isfilecontent.read(buf2)) > 0) {
             fileOutputpdf.write(buf2, 0, b_read);
         }
         fileOutputpdf.flush();
         //closed the output stream
         fileOutputpdf.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle IOException
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```