# Move first word at end of String with new characters

Tags: java, string, split, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a list of words with the format `word1**word2`

I want to put the firt word at the end of the String like `word2 - word1`.

how can I split the first word without `**` and add a `-` before paste the word at the end?

I want to let the lines read from a file `words.txt` and create a new file `new-words.txt`

For example, I want `Bibi**Tina`  to be converted in `Tina - Bibi`

Edit:
I tried a new code.
Now I get the right output on the Console but the new created file is empty.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main { 
 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
     String line = null;
        try {
            File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\new-words.txt");
            FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\Users\\\\PC\\\\Desktop\\words.txt"));
            
            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.contains("\\*\\*\\yok")) {
                String[] a = line.split("\\*\\*");
                System.out.println(a[1] + "  - " + a[0]);
                }
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String s : lines)
            out.write(s);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Please explain what " it didn't work" means. Either provide a sample input, output, and expected output, or if an exception/error occurred, please provide that.

Comment: I get this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method write(int) in the type FileOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (String)

 at Main.main(Main.java:23)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [official java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). There are 3 options of how to use the `write` method, and none of them take a string as an argument.

> - **void write(*byte[] b*)**: Writes b.length bytes from the specified byte array
>   to this file output stream.
> - **void write(*byte[] b, int off, int len*)**: Writes
>   len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this
>   file output stream.
> - **void write(*int b*)**: Writes the specified byte to this
>   file output stream.

You need to convert your string into a byte[] in order to write it to a file using a file output stream.
See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972105/9661573) which talks about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.  Use `replaceAll` which takes a regular expression.

- `(\\w+)` - capture a word
- `\\*\\*` - back to back asterisks (must be escaped as they have special regex properties)
- `$1` and `$2` - back references to the just captured words.

```
String s = "This is a test word1**word2";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\*\\*(\\w+)", "$2 - $1");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
This is a test word2 - word1
```

If the phrase isn't matched, the original string will be returned.

So in your case it would be the following:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     line = line.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\*\\*(\\w+)", "$2 - $1");
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
star.split('**').reverse().join('-')
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: I don't want to reverse the rest of the string. I edited my post, can you look again please